# jquery get HTML of an element stripping the style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Is it possible to obtain the raw HTML of an element or is it possible to get the HTML without the "style" attribute ? Consider the following example,

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
       some text
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, I apply some animation/CSS to the "inner" element.

```
​$('.inner').animate({
    'margin': '-10px'
});​​
```

When I get the HTML of the "outer" element using `console.log($('.outer').html());`, I get the following

```
<div class="inner" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; ">
       some text
   </div>
```

But, I actually need this only

```
<div class="inner">
       some text
   </div>
```

What is the simplest way to get that output ?? I don't need to create a backup of the element before applying the animate() or css().

Thank you.

Comment: "When I get the HTML of the "outer" element". How are you getting it? Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: try `$('.inner').removeAttr("style");` to remove the style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove the style attribute totally (and don't want it back), use the code below:

```
/* Working code */ 
$(".outer").find(".inner").removeAttr('style').end().html();

/* Explanation of working code */
$(".outer")                     // Get the outer element
           .find(".inner")      // Find the inner div
           .removeAttr('style') // Remove the attribute from the inner div
           .end()               // Return to the outer div
           .html();             // Get outer div's HTML
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/Sr7SX/).

**jQuery Docs:**

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)
- [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)